# Getting child in DOM tree via querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Good day! I have read the articles about DOM tree and querySelector(All) and can work with it.Started wondering is it possible to get indirect child without selecting direct child first?
For example:

```
<body class ="page">
    <section class="parent">
      <div class="direct-child">
         <button type="button" class="direct-child__button"></button>
         <form class="indirect-child">
              <h2 class="indirect-child__title">Something</h2>
              <input type="text" class="indirect-child__input">
              <input type="text" class="indirect-child__input">
             <button type="submit" class="indirect-child__button">Submit</button>
         </form>
       </div>
    </section>
 </body>
```

**JS code:**

```
let pageSelector= document.querySelector(`.page`); //step 1
let parentSelector = pageSelector.querySelector(`.parent`); //step 2
let dChild = parentSelector.querySelector(`.direct-child`); //step 3
let iChild = dChild.querySelector(`.indirect-child`); //step 4
let element = iChild.querySelector(`.indirect-child__input`); //step 5
```

Is it possible to skip steps in here? Can i get the parent and indirect-child's element?

```
let pageSelector= document.querySelector(`.page`); //step 1
let parentSelector = pageSelector.querySelector(`.parent`); //step 2
let element = parentSelector.querySelector(`.indirect-child__input`); //step 5
```

Comment: ..yes, your code should work? `querySelector` can select any descendant that matches the selector

Comment: Well noted, thank you very much! @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @MrPrincerawat said is correct if that class doesn't exist anywhere else on the page. If you really need it to be the `indirect-child__input` that's inside `.parent` that's inside `.page`, you can put the whole selector together like you'd do in CSS.

`let element = document.querySelectorAll('.page .parent .indirect-child__input');`

(I used the "all" variant because your sample has two elements that match, and this'll give you them as a list.)

Literally any selector you can do in CSS, you can do in `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 2):

you can just pass id or class in queryselector and it will work just fine
Here:

```
let element = parentSelector.querySelector('.indirect-child__input');
```

This single line of code will work